# pynput - Not seeing capital letters

Tags: python-3.x, pynput

pynput not seeing cap letters directly.

Using pynput to catch combo keys. Able to read 'h' but not 'H'. Python 3.6, windows 10 machine, tried running as admin. Able to see Key.shift and Key.ctrl_l but not the proper converted key. I hope I'm clear.

Perhaps my code below is missing something or it currently is not able to read combo-keys.

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener


def look_for_key(key):

    letter = str(key)
    letter = letter.replace("'", "")

    if letter == 'Key.esc':
        return False

    print(letter)  


with Listener(on_press = look_for_key) as l:
    l.join()
```

From seeing other posts and examples, I should see it print out "H" if that is typed, instead I see "h".

Comment: Can you show such an example where "H" would supposedly be printed?

Comment: I'm not sure what you need. The above code would print out 'h' , if I press shift-h it prints "Key.shift h" instead of "H". For example a % can never be seen and if I'm looking for odd hot-key combos such as !+@, it can't be seen.

Comment: Well, 'shift' and 'h' are the keys you press on the keyboard, so that's certainly not wrong. You wrote that there were examples were `H` would be printed instead. If you showed such an example, someone might be able to help you figure out what the difference is between that example and your code.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, the above code should show the result of all the duel function keys. Currently it is not.

Comment: I knew I wasn't crazy. This guys tutorial shows how it's catching the alt action of keys. https://youtu.be/WkE0QJu3ug8?t=374 . But it looks like others are having this issue also. I've tried on both Win 10 and Win 7 machines.

Answer (score 0):

You can detect if the key pressed equals **Key.caps_lock** and based on that, print or modify the key with the **upper() method**, but you have to transform the key to string.
Second step, create a global variable **'count'** that will save the number of times the caps_lock key is pressed, in order to detect if the caps_lock was turned off. If the count variable is **odd** the program will print an uppercase key, otherwise, in lowercase.

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
count = 0
def on_press(key):
    global count

    if key == Key.caps_lock:
        count = count + 1
    elif count%2!=0:
        print(str(key).upper())
    else:
        print(str(key).lower())
with Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```